# Returning the count when there are no matches MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  games.id AS id,
  games.ean AS ean,
  games.title AS title,
  games.developer AS developer,
  reviews.NoReviews AS NoReviews 
FROM
  games 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      ean,
      COUNT(*) AS NoReviews 
    FROM
      reviews 
    GROUP BY ean) reviews 
    ON games.ean = reviews.ean 
WHERE games.genre = genre
```

Im having issue with the above code only returning data when there is a game with a review but not returning anything when the game has no reviews which is what i want it to do

for example if a game has no reviews it should still return the game from that genre but with a count of 0 for no reviews. When i try changing anything it wont send any data back even when there is a match. So i have reverted it back to the working method i had above.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `Inner join` to `left join`,Inner join will gives you the record for the matches only while left join will give you all rows from left table even if there are no matches found

```
SELECT 
  games.id AS id,
  games.ean AS ean,
  games.title AS title,
  games.developer AS developer,
  reviews.NoReviews AS NoReviews 
FROM
  games 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      ean,
      COUNT(*) AS NoReviews 
    FROM
      reviews 
    GROUP BY ean) reviews 
    ON games.ean = reviews.ean 
WHERE games.genre = genre
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Query :-

```
SELECT games.id AS id,games.ean AS ean, games.title AS title, games.developer AS developer, reviews.NoReviews AS NoReviews
FROM games left outer join
(SELECT ean, COUNT(*) as NoReviews 
FROM reviews GROUP BY ean) reviews 
ON games.ean = reviews.ean 
WHERE games.genre=genre
```

Left outer join will show all records from left table , and matching records from right table.

Comment: thanks it has worked now also what is the outer part about as from the answer below a left join did the same thing